# How to check which terminals are open using c

Tags: c, terminal

I am trying to check which terminals are open using C.  When I type "w" into the terminal it shows that only 4 terminals are open (which is actually how many terminals I have open).  However, when I run this code it tells me that there are about 20 open.  How do I fix this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>


const char pts[] = "/dev/pts/";
int s1=0;

FILE *fp = NULL;
char *terminal[4];
char* check;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int i;
char strDev[100]; 

for(i=0; i<100; i++){
  sprintf(strDev, "%s%d", pts, i);
  printf("Opening %s...\n", strDev); fflush(stdout);

  if((fp = fopen(strDev, "w")) == NULL) ;
  else{

  printf("\tOpened %s\n", strDev); fflush(stdout);

    terminal[s1] = strDev;
    s1++;
  }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this with portable C; the standard provides no means for it. It needs to be done in some system-specific way, so you need to at least specify your operating system.

Comment: For the record, the `w` command uses the `utmp` file, so if you want to do the same as what it does, see the manpage. That's not exactly the same thing as checking what terminals are open, though.

Comment: Your program is checking how many terminals it can open, not which ones are already opened.

Answer (score 1):

Running `w` is reasonably portable.  But only the count is needed, not the headers.  The first line of the headers *usually* is a status line giving the actual number of users (but awkward to parse in C), and the remaining line of the headers shows the column names, beginning in the first column.  There is ***no*** standard for `w` or its format.  POSIX does describe [`who`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/who.html), but avoids describing the format it uses.  So, for `w`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
    int result = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = popen("w", "r")) != 0) {
        int lineno = 0;
        char *buffer = 0;
        size_t size = 0;
        int head = 0;
        while (getline(&buffer, &size, fp) > 0) {
            if (lineno++ == 0) {
                head = (*buffer != ' ') ? 2 : 1;
            } else if (head++ > 1) {
                ++result;
            }
        }
        pclose(fp);
    }
    printf("%d terminals are open\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to know which terminals are in use, the way to do that would be to use the column information from the header and select the text from following lines.  With no applicable standard, the width (and order) of the columns can vary from one system to another, so any solution using specific offsets and string-lengths will be flawed.

However, for displaying a list of available (unused) terminals, you are on your own, because on some systems the corresponding special devices would be protected so that ordinary (non-privileged) programs could not open them, only test their existence.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `system` command to do just what the `w` command does you're using:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char command[128];
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "w");
    system(command);

return 0;
}
```